# Link xcode framework against another framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks, static-linking

Let's say I am creating an Xcode framework that will be depending on another framework:

**MyFramework**

- produces `libmyframework.a`
- in its code it references a symbol `third_party_symbol` from a third party framework

**ThirdPartyFramework**

- produces `libthirdpartyframework.a`
- contains the symbol `third_party_symbol`

Now I wish to distribute MyFramework in a way that `libmyframework.a` should not contain the implementation of `third_party_symbol`, but only a reference to it. And then I will tell the end user to include both MyFramework and ThirdPartyFramework for it to work.

For now I am putting the `-lthirdpartyframework` framework flag when compiling `libmyframework.a`. And end user does not have to include ThirdPartyFramework in their app to make it work, so I suspect `libmyframework.a` already includes the implementation of `third_party_symbol`, which is not what I want.

But if I omit `-lthirdpartyframework` it doesn't compile.

**So my question is:** How to include only the reference but not the actual implementation `third_party_symbol` in MyFramework. But let the linker link against the implementation from `libthirdpartyframework.a` at the end user's compilation process?